# Get and Use Background Color to apply the same color in other window

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, window, background-color

I am doing a Chrome Extension and I need to get the background color of the current page and change the background color of a window to the color obtained previously, how can I do that in javascript ( with or without jQuery ) and if necessary html or css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DOMObject.style.backgroundColor and window.getComputedStyle:

```
<object to set background color of>.style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName(“BODY”)[0], null).getPropertyValue("background-color")
```

You can find documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0):

> try this active in same window :

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
    body {
        background: #279DDD;
    }
</style>
<p>Click the button to put the new window in the current window.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        debugger;
    var bgColor=$('body').css('background');
    var myWindow = window.open("", "_self");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>I replaced the current window.</p>");
    myWindow.document.body.style.background = bgColor;
}
</script>
```

> or this in new window
>
> try this :

```
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #279DDD;
        }
    </style>
    <p>Click the button to put the new window in the current window.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            debugger;
        var bgColor=$('body').css('background');
        var myWindow = window.open("", "_self");
        myWindow.document.write("<p>I new window.</p>");
        myWindow.document.body.style.background = bgColor;
    }
    </script>
```